# Ghostscript Error when executing from Java

Tags: java, ghostscript

I am trying to execute a ghostscript command from my Java Program using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).

The command that i am using to generate PDF/A File is:

```
command = "/usr/local/bin/gs  -q  -dPDFA=2  -dBATCH  -dNOPAUSE  -sColorConversionStrategy=RGB  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -dPSFitPage  -dFastWebView=true  -dDOPDFMARKS  -sOutputFile=" + mergedPDFFile + " " + pdfaDefFile + " " + inputPDFFile + " " + pdfMarksFile;
```

It works perfectly fine when the input PDF file size is less than 1 MB. However, when the input PDF File size is greater than 1 MB, the output does not get generated.

The code that i have written in Java is:

```
 private void executeCommand(String command) {
        Process p = null;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", command});
             String s1 = null;
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((s1= reader.readLine()) != null) {
                slf4jLogger.info("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" + s1);
            }
            String s = null;
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                slf4jLogger.info("***********************" + s);
            }
            p.waitFor();
            int returnValue = p.exitValue();
            slf4jLogger.info("RETURN VALUE : " + returnValue);

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            slf4jLogger.error("ERROR: ********************" + e.toString(), e);
        } finally {
            slf4jLogger.info("END MY PROCESS:");
            if (p != null) {
                p.destroy();
            }
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume that if you run the command directly in a shell that it works fine without any errors? What's the logging output from your program?

Comment: That's correct. When running from shell, it works fine. When i run from the java program for file size greater than 1 MB,  there is no return value or anything in Error Stream.